# What steps can developers take to improve the graphics of their games?

Tags: graphics

My understanding is that the differences in graphic quality between games for systems like Xbox One and PS4 and Pixar-style movies stems from that the former are rendered in real-time.

But even with real-time rendering, it looks like some game makers can get rather nice looking results. An example below is about the new Gears of War game:

[image: scene from Gears of War]

Above image is from [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/g-tgXPF8foQ) posted by GameSpot. So admittedly it could be from a video (e.g. a promo) that has been rendered more than the actual game.

Anyway so what I wanted to ask is, are games solely dependent on the real time rendering on the target system, or are there some steps developers can take (besides the obvious: start with as good graphics as possible) to improve the graphics in their game?

**Edit:** here I am referring strictly to in-game graphics.

Comment: Are you talking specifically about in-game graphics or cutscenes? While it's getting much better these days, cinematic scenes are much different than in-game graphics, even if they are real-time/mechanim.

Comment: @Fuzzy Logic, I have now edited my question (I was referring only to in-game graphics)